# Use Python to Search and Replace thorn (þ) Character with Pipe (|)

Tags: python

I am trying to use python to find thorn "þ" character, and replace with pipe "|". For example, the file has contents like 125650þ383736þ392647. Below is my code:

```
f = codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8', mode='r+')
contents = f.read()
if u'\u00FE' in contents:
    print 'Found thorn'
```

I got error on contents = f.read() line: 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 7: invalid start byte

It seems like file object f can't decode thorn character. What's the problem here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use find() function.

Comment: Is the file actually UTF-8 encoded?  If the UTF-8 decoder chokes then that usually indicates that the file content is encoded with a different encoding.

Comment: My guess is that the file is encoded in `latin1`, not `utf-8`. If just replacing `utf-8` with `latin1` does not work, please post a hex dump of the first 8 characters or so of the file to check the encoding.

Comment: Try different encodings on the open method... http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common cause of decoding errors is that you are using the wrong encoding.  In this case, it looks like your file is encoded in Windows-1252 or latin-1, not UTF-8.  I am pretty sure this is the case because `0xfe` is the code point for Latin small letter thorn for those codecs.

For example:

```
>>> print '125650\xfe383736\xfe3926'.decode('latin-1')
125650þ383736þ3926
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file does not contain valid UTF8 encodings, nor is your `u'\u00FE'` the correct UTF8 encoding of `þ`:

```
>>> u'þ'.encode('utf8')
'\xc3\xbe'
```

It looks like the encoding you're expecting is latin-1:

```
>>> u'þ'.encode('latin-1')
'\xfe'
```

So you want:

```
f = codecs.open(path, encoding='latin-1', mode='r+')
contents = f.read()
if u'þ' in contents:
    print 'Found thorn'
```